# How can I set RetroArch to use the JXD S7300's controllers?

Tags: controllers, android, emulation, retroarch

I have a JXD S7300, it's a gaming tablet based on Android:

[image: JXD S7300]

Does anyone know how to set up the input controllers through RetroArch?

The native emulators of this tablet, use to fail in the directional controls.

Answer (score 2):

Some users have already send Squarepusher, (the builder of RetroArch) the input command codes for the S7300, for him to use in a future build of Retroarch.

I don't have the device so I can't say if there is a way around it until he makes it a "known" device later on. Hopefully release #13, will have the S7300 hardware implemented.